# How can I determine if at least one radio button inside a groupbox is checked?

Tags: c#

For example:

I have `radiobutton1`, and `radiobutton2`, both in the `groupbox1`.
I also have `radiobutton3` and `radiobutton4`, in `groupbox2`.

Is it possible to take action if at least `radiobutton1` or `radiobutton2` is checked? If it was just two radio buttons it would be simple, but I have around 200 radio buttons across 30 groupboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially do something like this:

```
if (groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(x => x.Checked)) {
    // at least one radiobutton in groupbox1 is checked
}
```

Comment: had no idea such controls existed, thank you